# Localization of variables in Windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch, script, localization

> I'm declaring and defining 5 strings, which I then perform some
> analysis on via function calls. The first function calculates the
> length of the strings, and the second count the spaces in the strings.
> The last two functions are not implemented yet. When I run the batch
> script, I get several errors saying "Missing operand". I think the
> problem has to do with localization of variables. Can anyone figure
> out how to solve the problem? Does the line setlocal EnableExtensions
> EnableDelayedExpansion ... endlocal also make the variables in the
> block local besides enable extensions and delayed expansion?

```
@REM File:      String analysis.bat
@REM Author:    Jakob Kjeldberg Andersen

@echo off

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

chcp 65001 > nul

color 0A

title String analysis

set /a Count=0

set /a Count+=1 & set String_!Count!="This is a test."
set /a Count+=1 & set String_!Count!="This_is_a_test."
set /a Count+=1 & set String_!Count!="        This is a test."
set /a Count+=1 & set String_!Count!="This is a test.        "
set /a Count+=1 & set String_!Count!="    This is a test.    "

set /a Start=1
set /a Step=1
set /a Stop=!Count!

set Separatorline=--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

echo !Separatorline! & echo. & echo Strings: & echo.

FOR /L %%X IN (!Start!,!Step!,!Stop!) do (

    echo %%X: !String_%%X! & echo.

)

echo !Separatorline! & echo. & echo Stringslengths: & echo.

FOR /L %%X IN (!Start!,!Step!,!Stop!) do (

    call :StringLength !String_%%X! , Length

    echo %%X: !Length! & echo.

)

echo !Separatorline! & echo. & echo Number of spaces in strings: & echo.

FOR /L %%X IN (!Start!,!Step!,!Stop!) do (

    call :SpaceCount !String_%%X! , NumberOfSpaces

    echo %%X: !NumberOfSpaces! & echo.

)

endlocal
 
pause&goto:eof

::==============================================================================

:StringLength StrVar , [RtnVar]

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set /a Length=0
set String="%~1#"

for %%P in ( 4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1 ) do (

    if "!String:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" (
        
        set /a Length+=%%P      
        set String=!String:~%%P!

    )

)

endlocal & if "%~2" equ "" (echo !Length!) else set /a %~2=!Length!

exit /B 0

::==============================================================================

:SpaceCount StrVar , [RtnVar]

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set String="%~1"
set /a NumberOfSpaces=0
set /a Start=1
set /a Step=1
set /a Skip=0
set /a Keep=1

call :StringLength !String! , Length

if !Length! equ 0 goto End

set /a Stop=!Length!

FOR /L %%X IN (!Start!,!Step!,!Stop!) DO (

    call set Char=!!String:~!Skip!,!Keep!!!

    if "!Char!" == " " set /a NumberOfSpaces+=1
    
    set /a Skip+=1
    
)

:End

endlocal & if "%~2" equ "" (echo !NumberOfSpaces!) else set /a %~2=!NumberOfSpaces!

exit /B 0

::==============================================================================

:WordCount StrVar , [RtnVar]

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Not yet implemented.

endlocal

exit /B 0

::==============================================================================

:WordLength StrVar , WordNumber , [RtnVar_WordLen] , [RtnVar_StartPos] , [RtnVar_EndPos]

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Not yet implemented.

endlocal

exit /B 0
```

Comment: Why are you working with batch rather than **PowerShell**?  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/77e51894-c591-469f-b3d3-982ab4f76ca7/if-else-if-condition-in-batch-files?forum=ITCG

Comment: I only learned that PowerShell existed pretty late, and it seemed like a big task to learn it. Besides there are many batch scripts out there, so it's a good thing to know your batch.

Comment: I only learned of it's existence pretty late, and it seemed like a big task to learn it.

Comment: You certainly find a lot of _examples_ on the internet because it's been around forever. But you only need to know it if your job requires you to maintain old code. In **PowerShell**, this defines a string: `'$a = 'Hello world. How many spaces?''`. The length is a built-in property: `$a.Length`. This counts spaces: `([Char[]]$a).Where({ $_ -eq ' ' }).Count`. Basic word count: `($a -split ' ').count`. Sure, there's a learning curve, but it's worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more to improve in your script. However, here is merely answer to your question.

For example in `:StringLength` function is the `Length` variable local hence `!Length!` is not more defined after `endlocal` at execution time:

```
endlocal & if "%~2" equ "" (echo !Length!) else set /a %~2=!Length!
rem                               ↑↑↑↑↑↑                    ↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

However, `%Length%` is still valid (defined in *parsing* time) so the line should be

```
endlocal & if "%~2" equ "" (echo %Length%) else set /a %~2=%Length%
```

Read more in `SETLOCAL`: [*Set options to control the visibility of environment variables in a batch file.*](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) and subsequent [`EnableDelayedExpansion`](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

> Delayed Expansion will cause variables within a batch file to be
> expanded at execution time rather than at parse time, this option is
> turned on with the `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` command.

Comment: Thank you very much JosefZ! Now I have something to work with!